# How to solve svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL and svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate untrusted error?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

How do I solve this error:

> **Error**
>
> Source control operation failed:
> svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'Url path'
> svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate untrusted

Comment: There is a dirty workaround: login as the CCNET service user, try to do a checkout from the SVN repo using TortoiseSVN, then `Accept the certificate permanently` when prompted.

Answer (score 3):

the certificate is probably user based.
if you run CCNet console and not CCNet service, does it work ?

if so, run CCNet service as that user.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in latest Subversion 1.8 regarding SSL certificate verification:

1. Check for hostname is case-sensitive, while it should be case-insensitive
2. Subversion doesn't display reason why certificate is not trusted

Both issues fixed in Subversion 1.8.3:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.3/CHANGES

> - ra_serf: ignore case when checking certificate common names (r1514763)
> - ra_serf: output ssl cert verification failure reason (r1514785 et al)

So I recommend you upgrade to Subversion 1.8.3 and see why certificate is not trusted.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the server (i.e. local network) you can ignore the cert. Just add this parameters:

`--non-interactive --trust-server-cert`

Example:

```
svn info -r HEAD --non-interactive --trust-server-cert
```